# Google Firebase: How to authenticate users with Snapchat?

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My app uses Google Firebase as a backend and I am trying to authenticate users using Snapchat (https://kit.snapchat.com), which is not yet supported in Firebase's list of authentication options. Is there a work around? Should I just manually reconcile the snapchatID with my Database and track the user's log in status manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use any form of authentication that isn't directly supported by Firebase Authentication, and you use need to use that to secure direct user access to products like Realtime Database, Firestore, and Cloud storage (via security rules), then the **only** truly secure way of implementing this is by [building a custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth).

A full explanation of how this works is too long for Stack Overflow, but the documentation is complete. Basically, you will implement a backend that uses the Firebase Admin SDK to [create custom ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), and the client app will use those to sign in.

It's not secure to simply check IDs for equality in the client app. Client app code can be compromised.  The authorization should come from security rules or some backend that you control.

It's entirely possible that someone has already written some code for custom auth with Snapchat, so maybe a web search will reveal that, or give you some hints on how to get started.